# Allowing multiple mappings in Elastic Search 6

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

I am upgrading from Elastic 5.6.16 to 6.8.13 and it's complaining about
"Rejecting mapping update to...as the final mapping would have more than 1 type"

Without switching to single mapping, is there a workaround to use multiple mapping in ElasticSearch 6?

I have tried updating the Index settings with: "index.mapping.single_type": "false"

but it complains about that setting not being a thing.

Does anyone have any other recommendations/ways to resolve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, elasticsearch version 6.X only supports one type per index in your mappings.

The setting `index.mapping.single_type` was to be used in version 5.6 set to `true` to prepare your index to have the same behavior as the ones on version 6.X, this setting does not exist in version 6.X if I'm not wrong.